# Replace text inside string

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I have a string with the following text and I need to substitute several characters:

```
zpl = "Test text {A1} - test text {A2} - test text {A3}";
```

I want to replace the {A?} with a value from a Datatable. This works fine for me with Visual Studio 2017, but the 2012 with which I have to compile tells me unexpected character $:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    zpl = zpl.Replace($"{{A{i}}}", row[0][i].ToString());
}
```

I don't know how to make it work with Studio 2012.

Comment: You have to go back to using `string.Format` or just plain string concatenation. `string.Format("{{A{0}}}", i)` or `"{A" + i + "}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$"{{A{i}}}"
```

(which is new in [C#6](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#string-interpolation)) is the same as

```
string.Format("{{A{0}}}", i)
```

So your code becomes

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    zpl = zpl.Replace(string.Format("{{A{0}}}", i), row[0][i].ToString());
}
```